# c# ADO,Sql server Unselect() function from datagriview

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, oledb

I have downloaded a c# sql server ADO project i'm struggling to understand the part of `this.dataGrid1.UnSelect(this.dataGrid1.CurrentRowIndex);`
i dont see function definition for Unselect function, I cant figure out if its a user defined function or buildin function.
The error message is Systems.Windows.Forms.DataGridView does not contain definition for 'Unselect' and no extension method 'Unselect' accepting a first argument of type Sytems.Windows.Forms.DataGridView could be found (are you missing using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
private void btFirst_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {
        if((currManager!=null)&(currManager.Count>0)) 
        {
          fnClearStatusbarPanel2();
          fnSelectUnselectLastFirstRow(0);
          //set the position at the first record 0
          currManager.Position=0;
          //enable pushbuttons Next, Last
          fnEnableDisableButtons(this.btNext,this.btLast,"", true);
          //disable pushbuttons First, Previous
          fnEnableDisableButtons(this.btFirst, this.btPrevious,"First record...",false);            
          //display record numbers in the StatusBar
          fnDisplayRecordNumbers(); 
        }
     }

     private void fnSelectUnselectLastFirstRow (int posi)
     {
        //unselect the last selected/highlighted row    
        this.dataGrid1.UnSelect(this.dataGrid1.CurrentRowIndex);

        //select the last or first row
        this.dataGrid1.Select(posi);
     }
```

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: The [Unselect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.unselect(v=vs.110).aspx) method exists in the [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid(v=vs.110).aspx) class (an old class now made obsolete by the DataGridView class)

Comment: I have downloaded a c# sql server ADO project i'm struggling to understand the part of this.dataGrid1.UnSelect(this.dataGrid1.CurrentRowIndex); i dont see function definition for Unselect function, I cant figure out if its a user defined function or buildin function. The error message is Systems.Windows.Forms.DataGridView does not contain definition for 'Unselect' and no extension method 'Unselect' accepting a first argument of type Sytems.Windows.Forms.DataGridView could be found (are you missing using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Has I have said. DataGridView replaced DataGrid. DataGridView has no UnSelect method. DataGrid has it. If you want to run that project you have two choices: Upgrade it to use the DataGridView class instead of DataGrid, or replace the actual DataGridView class with the DataGrid one. Both options seem to be not easy for you as a beginner. I suggest to read https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms171628(v=vs.100).aspx